# Extracting UIImage from PHAsset video

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiimage, phaser-framework

I am trying to get preview image of video in swift.I have PHAsset and need to convert the it's preview image to UIImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome ! , To get the thumbnails from the videos first you need to get the PHAsset and then use the `PHCachingImageManager()` in order to request a thumbnail image from your video.

I will recommend you to check the 'options' area, so you can get the assets in the most suitable way for you.

follow the next code:

```
let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager()
var allAssetsinAlbum: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>!
var assetsInAlbum = [UIImage]()

func getThumbnail(){
    let options = PHFetchOptions()
    options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", "YourAlbumName")// Get the assets
    let album = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: options)
    ///- Note: It 's also a good idea to check if the album is available, not doing it here
    let thumbnailSize = CGSize(width: 160, height: 160)// you can customize the size here
    allAssetsinAlbum = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: album.firstObject!, options: nil) as PHFetchResult<PHAsset>
    let limit = allAssetsinAlbum.count
    if limit != 0 {
        for i in 0...limit-1 {
            let isVideo = allAssetsinAlbum.object(at: i).mediaType == .video ?  true : false /// Check if it is a VIDEO
            let options = PHImageRequestOptions()//Options: How the thumbnails are obtained
            options.isSynchronous = true
            options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true //get those saved in iCloud
            options.deliveryMode = .fastFormat// fastest but the quality is not very good
            imageManager.requestImage(for: allAssetsinAlbum.object(at: i) , targetSize: thumbnailSize, contentMode: .default, options: options, resultHandler: { asset, _ in /// save video THUMBNAILS
                if isVideo{
                    assetsInAlbum.append(asset!)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Then I am guessing that you want to display this in a List or something.

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    
    getThumbnail()
    let columns = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 100, maximum: 100))]
    
    
    return LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20 ) {
        ForEach(Array(assetsInAlbum.enumerated()), id:\.offset) { index, element in
            ZStack{
                Image(uiImage: element)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                    .clipped()
                    .cornerRadius(5)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you find it useful !~